# How can I monitor individual containers resource usage in LXD/C

Tags: lxc, container, lxd

I would like to be able to view which individual containers are using what percentage of CPU, memory etc.

I have installed HTOP but it doesn't tell me which container, and I have 20+ containers running.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for something like this for a while. The closest thing I've found, and only very recently, is [systemd-cgtop](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd-cgtop.1.html).

I use it with these options: `systemd-cgtop --depth=1 -p`

- Depth controls how deep in the cgroup tree is displayed. By default, cgtop shows info from all processes in all your containers. If you just want to see how many resources the container is using overall, `--depth=1` does that.
- `-p` orders by process name. Default ordering is by resource usage, so the list order constantly changes. `-p` orders by process so the list stays static and it's easier to monitor individual changes.

Here's example output from one of my lxd servers:

[image: cgtop]

The `lxc.payload` entries are the containers.